# Difference between IMap.delete and IMap.evict

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am working currently with a simple `Hazelcast` `IMAP<String, byte[]>`.

If I delete entries from the map with `myMap.delete(key)`, the value is successfully deleted from the map. Parallel of that I monitor the `JVM` and I see that the object is never removed from the Heap-Memory by the `GC`(there must be still a reference to the object).

From my point of view it seems that only our `Hazelcast TTL Eviction policy` clears the `heap`. So my question is, should I use `myMap.evict(key)` instead of `delete` to clear the Java-Memory? And if yes why?
What are the differences between `evict` and `delete` on `IMap`?

Comment: Can you please share how you noticed that the entry occupies the heap after GC even you call `delete(key)`?

Comment: `evict` and `delete` removes the entry from memory in the same way. `evict` does not remove it from the underlying `MapStore` and that is the only difference. So, from memory usage perspective, they will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If your Imap is backed by a DB table

- Delete : Entry removed from Imap & DB table
- Evict : Entry removed ONLY from Imap. It is still present at DB table

Evict is internally used by HZ, to clear cache which has to removed as per Eviction Policy.

Now, this Eviction just happened from the Imap, not the DB table corresponding it.

Taking example

**Case 1** : Hz have 2 entries: (K1,V1) (K2,V2)

Evict(K1)

at this moment, Imap has only 1 value(K2,V2) will DB table will have both entries (K1,V1) (K2,V2)

Get(K1)

lookup will happen in this manner cache --> NearCache --> DB table

here, you will get your response from DB table, and the cache(Iamp) will again be populated with (K1,V1)

**Case 2**: Hz have 2 entries: (K1,V1) (K2,V2)

Remove(K1)

Entry is now removed from both Imap & DB Table

Get(K1) results null